# Insert link doesn't work as expected

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

Whether this is a bug might be open to interpretation. However, in the spirit of continuous improvement I thought I'd bring this up. When inserting a link we get the following prompt.

[image]

Placing an optional title as indicated fails. Simply changing the notification removing the text between quotes IMHO would suffice as it rapidly becomes clear to even the casual observer where to place the title once you've added the link as you get this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works fine for me. Note that this is the title, **not** the alt text. The text in the "enter image description" part is the alt text, used when the image couldn't be shown. The title is shown when you mouseover the link, and in markdown looks like so (`foo` in this example):

```
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://example.com "foo"
```

[enter link description here](http://example.com)

[image]

Comment: Ahh. Thank you for the clarification. Perhaps "optional mouseover title" would add some clarity.

Comment: @ElderGeek And where is the acceptance it this answer helped you?  **>:-)**

Comment: @Fabby I was hoping for some further discussion on the topic..